# I cannot understand the np.where result function

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
tt = np.asarray([[1,4,5],[3,1,5],[1,4,5],[3,1,5]])
np.where(tt < [2])
```

but I have this output :

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

I don't understand why I have this output, the content of those two arrays indicats what exactly?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Because that is the correct output for the definition of "less than" between lists.  Please read the appropriate documentation, and update your question with a *specific* question.

Comment: Those are the row and column indices of the 4 `1's` in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer. My problem was that I was expecting a table with all the values that are smaller than two. I just understood the output now, the first table shows the row indexes and the second one shows the column indexes. And this indicates that the [Ri,Ci] element (the ith row and the ith column) is less than two.